# tkinter grid manager doesnt fit buttons correctly

Tags: python, tkinter

I have an app with 1 video frame and 5 Buttons. I want the video frame on top and the buttons nicely under the frame all in one row.

Here is my code:

```
    self.root = tki.Tk()
    self.panel = None
    #create a button, that when pressed, will take the current
    #frame and save it to file
    btn= tki.Button(self.root, text="Snapshot!", command=self.takeSnapshot)
    btn.grid(sticky = tki.S)

    btnturnl= tki.Button(self.root, text="Left", command = self.EinsRechts)
    btnturnl.grid(sticky = tki.SW)

    btnturnl2= tki.Button(self.root, text="Two Left", command = self.ZweiRechts)
    btnturnl2.grid(sticky = tki.SW)

    btnturnr= tki.Button(self.root, text="Right", command = self.EinsLinks)
    btnturnr.grid(sticky = tki.SE)

    btnturnr2= tki.Button(self.root, text="Two Right", command = self.ZweiLinks)
    btnturnr2.grid(sticky = tki.SE)
    self.panel = tki.Label(image=image) #in this panel the video feed gets shown
    self.panel.image = image
    self.panel.grid(sticky = tki.N)
```

This is how it really looks:

[what am I doing wrong?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zpUTL.png)

I am not that experienced with Tkinter so if I maybe have missed a function that would be better suited for me I'd gladly change my code.

If you have questions feel free to ask and thanks for the help.

Comment: `.grid()` needs row and column numbers so it has some idea of where you want to place the widgets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace:

```
btn.grid(sticky = tki.S)
...
btnturnl.grid(sticky = tki.SW)
...
btnturnl2.grid(sticky = tki.SW)
...
btnturnr.grid(sticky = tki.SE)
...
btnturnr2.grid(sticky = tki.SE)
...
self.panel.grid(sticky = tki.N)
```

with:

```
btn.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky = tki.S)
...
btnturnl.grid(row=1, column=1, sticky = tki.SW)
...
btnturnl2.grid(row=1, column=2, sticky = tki.SW)
...
btnturnr.grid(row=1, column=3, sticky = tki.SE)
...
btnturnr2.grid(row=1, column=4, sticky = tki.SE)
...
self.panel.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=5, sticky = tki.N)
```

If you don't specify `row` or `column` numbers in a `grid` call `row` defaults to `last_row_no + 1` and `column` defaults to `0`.

Review below the code snippets that produce *identical* GUIs:

```
import tkinter as tk


root = tk.Tk()
label = tk.Label(root, text="Label")
button = tk.Button(root, text="Button")

label.grid()                            # implicit
button.grid()

root.mainloop()
```

is identical to:

```
import tkinter as tk


root = tk.Tk()
label = tk.Label(root, text="Label")
button = tk.Button(root, text="Button")

label.grid(row=0, column=0)             # explicit
button.grid(row=1, column=0)

root.mainloop()
```

It is suggested to be explicit, latter is the better code, to quote zen of python`(import this)`:

```
"Explicit is better than implicit."
```

Comment: thanks for the help. This works really good. Is there any option to make the buttons stretch when you change window size? Or make the program always start in full window mode?

Comment: Yes there are. Search for `sticky`, `grid_rowconfigure`, `grid_columnconfigure`, `weight`, and `-fullscreen`.

Comment: Nice, is it actually possible to stretch a video feed and get it to fit to the window size? I am confident to get this right with the buttons but the video feed or better said panel.

Comment: @Xenoshell I wouldn't know about that. It is possible to resize image, so if the video is images frame by frame I don't see why not.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the actual column and row arguments:

http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/grid.htm#patterns

Answer (score 1):

take this example to achieve what you want .Using the `row` and `column` works like excel worksheet so you can increase the value position it where you want it.

```
btn= tki.Button(self.root, text="Snapshot!", command=self.takeSnapshot)
btn.grid(row=1 , column=2, sticky = tki.S)

btnturnl= tki.Button(self.root, text="Left", command = self.EinsRechts)
btnturnl.grid(row=3 , column=5, sticky = tki.SW)
```